# Partial fraction decomposition not working

Tags: fractions, partial-fractions

While trying to do partial fraction decomposition on $$\frac{x^4 +1}{x(x^2+1)^2}$$ I first equated it to $$\frac{A}{x}+\frac{Bx+1}{x^2+1}+\frac{C}{(x^2+1)^2}$$

On solving this, by adding the fractions, you get $$\frac{x^2(A+B)+A+x}{x^3+x}+\frac{C}{x^4+2x^2+1}$$ so obviously $A$ has to be equal to $1$ for the numerator's constant to be 1, and similarly, going forward, $B=-1$ and $C$ is -2, but when you write it out, you get an extra $x^5+2x^2+x$ in the numerator.

As far as I know, the method works everywhere. Can someone tell me where I've messed up here?

Comment: You assumed the numerator in the middle summand to be a linear polynomial, so why the last one term only has a constant numerator?

Comment: Isn't that the general form? I think with how this works, as per [this](math.stackexchange.com/a/185273/527653)answer, it looks like the last one should have a constant numerator.

Comment: See [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition?wprov=sfla1). The last numerator should also be a linear polynomial.

Comment: Below 'Suppose Q(x) = (x − α)rS(x) and S(α) ≠ 0. ... will involve the powers of (x − α). ', in the 'procedure' section of the wiki article you linked, there *is* an equation for the case of repeated linear factors, but aren't those constants in the numerator?

Comment: Alright, directly, you shall assume the fraction be $$ \frac Ax + \frac {Bx + C} {x^2+1} + \frac{Dx + E}{(x^2+1)^2}.$$ The case when repeated linear factors appears cannot apply to your question because the summand in question has a denominator being a power of a **quadratic polynomial**, not linear, and the numerator cannot just be constants.

Comment: The middle summand has a linear polynomial in the numerator as that term is a combination of two fractions with their denominators having complex parts.

Comment: Also I should put it out that the part I want you to read is "Over the Reals -- General result" in the link.

Comment: Yeah, but… if you don't use the standard form, then you will be getting nowhere in most cases… like right now :(

Comment: Oh, so the last equation in that section is the most generalised one, right? For literally every case? If so, can you post that third last comment as an answer so I can mark it as one?

Comment: Now we expect you to use what you have learned here to solve the problem, write it up, and post it as an answer here. It's a way to express your gratitude and to help the next student who comes along.

Comment: Today would be a good day to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't use the standard form, then you will be getting nowhere in most cases… like right now :(

The most general case is the following one [screenshot of the section "Over the reals---General Result" in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partial_fraction_decomposition?wprov=sfla1) link]:

[image: General case for partial fractions]

Comment: So, now we are copying Wikipedia screenshots to StackExchange...

Comment: Is this deed highly controversial? I shouldn't do this? 

Comment: I am not an authority here, wait for possible comments of others. - I would not do it personally.